# Why are the two results different in JSON.stringify?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I expected `JSON.stringify(all) === JSON.stringify(updatedAll2)` to be `false`, but it is `true`. And I don't understand the result of this. Can you explain why it comes out like this?

Here's my code:

```js
const all = {
  name: "oneny",
  schools: [{
      name: "Yorktown",
      students: 100
    },
    {
      name: "Stratford",
      students: 120
    },
    {
      name: "Washington & Lee",
      students: 200
    },
    {
      name: "Wakefield",
      students: 300
    },
  ],
};

const updatedAll = {
  ...all,
  schools: all.schools.map((e, i) => {
    return e.name === "Stratford" ? { ...e,
      students: 119
    } : e;
  }),
}

const updatedAll2 = {
  ...all,
  schools: all.schools.map((e, i) => {
    return e.name === "Stratford" ? { ...e,
      students: --e.students
    } : e;
  }),
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(all) === JSON.stringify(updatedAll));
console.log(JSON.stringify(all) === JSON.stringify(updatedAll2));
```

Comment: `--e.students` mutates the value. Did you mean `e.students - 1`?

Comment: `students: --e.students` modifies the value in `all` while including it in the new mapping, so they’re both 119 when you compare them. If you move the first comparison to before the `updatedAll2` declaration it will be false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), if the element passed to your callback is an object, then mutating it will also mutate the original object in the original array. To see this in action, try printing `all` after the `.map()` call. You will see that it has been changed.

```js
const all = {
  name: "oneny",
  schools: [{
      name: "Yorktown",
      students: 100
    },
    {
      name: "Stratford",
      students: 120
    },
    {
      name: "Washington & Lee",
      students: 200
    },
    {
      name: "Wakefield",
      students: 300
    },
  ],
};

const updatedAll = {
  ...all,
  schools: all.schools.map((e, i) => {
    return e.name === "Stratford" ? { ...e,
      students: 119
    } : e;
  }),
}

const updatedAll2 = {
  ...all,
  schools: all.schools.map((e, i) => {
    return e.name === "Stratford" ? { ...e,
      students: --e.students
    } : e;
  }),
}

// Print all, which has been mutated
console.log(all)

console.log(JSON.stringify(all) === JSON.stringify(updatedAll));
console.log(JSON.stringify(all) === JSON.stringify(updatedAll2));
```

Comment: Oh! I made a mistake! Thanks to you, I corrected this and it worked out well!